# DNS - Multiple SPF with different qualifiers

Tags: dns, server

I have these spf with difrent qualifiers (~all, -all, ?all):

```
v=spf1 ip4:30.138.5.211 ~all 
v=spf1 ip4:18.160.200.32 a ~all 
v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com -all
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ?all
```

According to the specification must be combined in a single txt record.

How can I combine?

I'm trying:

```
v=spf1 ip4:30.138.5.211 ~all ip4:18.160.200.32 a ~all include:spf.mandrillapp.com -all include:spf.protection.outlook.com ?all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are including the `all' mechanism four times with three different results.

You are giving four records, and saying that for `all` other IPs should be marked as `FAIL` `SOFTFAIL` and `NEUTRAL` (at which point it throws its toys out of the pram and tells you to make your mind up ;) )

The record you actually want is

```
 v=spf1 ip4:30.138.5.211 ip4:18.160.200.32 include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

P.S. You can verify SPF records at http://kitterman.com/spf/validate.html